# Laptop keyboard suddenly stopped working

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

I have linux mint 19.3 and this morning my laptop's keyboard stopped working out of no where. it works fine in recovery mode though.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Once in recovery mode you can check the logs, for example /var/log/kern.log, /var/log/Xorg.0.log, /home/your_graphical_user/.xsession.errors and see if there is any information or errors relating the keyboard.

Comment: it says "failed to load module libinput (loader failed, 7)" full log here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jT7Mzr3ckb

Answer (score 1):

```
[    81.150] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    81.151] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.so.2: version `LIBEVDEV_1_4' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput.so.10)
[    81.151] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    81.151] (II) Unloading libinput
[    81.151] (EE) Failed to load module "libinput" (loader failed, 7)
```

Good, that explains it. It might be a dependency problem (for example the library does not match what the program was waiting for). I'd run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and make sure all dependencies are ok.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try to reinstall the libinput module with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Comment: This didn't work but I found some weird dependcy problems when I was reinstalling https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QDmKYJZkhp/